# QLineEdit Validation for {[A-Z] [a-z][0-9]} text input

Tags: validation, qt4, expression, qlineedit

I want to accept a new username from the user in my application. I want the username string to contain only `A-Z` or `a-z` or `0-9`, and have a maxLength of 8. So I want to validate the input from `QLineEdit`. I went through the documentation but I am messed up with validators. How I can validate my `QLineEdit` for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [setInputMask](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) to specify the validation input mask, in your case you can use "N" or "n' to permit only characters in A-Z, a-z and 0-9 range. something like this:

```
lineEdit->setInputMask("nnnnnnnn;_"); // or NNNNNNNN;_
lineEdit->setCursorPosition(0);
```

You also can set [`QValidator`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qt-maemo/qvalidator.html#validate) instance to your `lineEdit`, via set [`setValidator`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlineedit.html#setValidator). This sets the `lineEdit` to only accept input that the validator, will accept. This will work in conjunction with edit masks

If you only need to restrict the max permitted length of the line edit: use [`setMaxLength`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qlineedit.html#maxLength-prop)

```
lineEdit->setMaxLength(8);
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Actually with inputMask it restricts the other other keys to detect. So I want it to accept and echo any key pressed and after user is done entering the username, I want to check the validation and can show login success or fail on my criteria. Could you please give me some code using QRegExValidator? It will be helpful to me.

Comment: Example usage of QRegExpValidator is in QRegExpValidator documentation in Qt docs (detailed description)